# Could not call Angular (v15) child component in Stackblitz

Tags: angular

I have no issue calling a child component on a notebook running Angular.
I believe it is version 12.

Normally I will call the child component from the default app component.

But in StackBlitz it only has index.html, so I call the child component
from there.

This is the main.ts.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {  InputButtonUnitComponent } from './input-button-unit/input-button-unit.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a>
    <br>
    <p> Hello </p>
    <label>Enter </label>
    <input>
    <button>click me</button>
    
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

I added the component at the index.html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <app-child></app-child>
  </body>
</html>
```

Attached is an image which hopefully shows the issue clearly.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you share your stackblitz link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `app-child` is not within your bootstrapped application.

Will either :

- move `app-child` within the template of `App`
- bootstrap an second angular app for `app-child`